# How to match cookies with different identifiers

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data of user cookies with a couple different identifiers, for example:

```
cookieid    identifier1 identifier2
A   Y   
B       X
C   Y   X
```

From that with joins I am able to to have pairs of cookies:

```
cookieid    cookieidmatch
A   A
A   C
B   B
B   C
C   A
C   C
```

The case it to find out, that A==C and B==C, meaning A==B, which is not obvious at the beggining.
And finally I need to have it deduplicated, so I need something like:

```
cookieid    cookieidmatch
A   A
A   B
A   C
```

With such data it will be easy to set that A, B, C cookie needs to be treated as the same one.
However, I don't know how to get to this point. This is the example I have 5 different identifiers. However as far as I checked it's not the issue as I am able to get to those two columns (cookieid and cookieidmatch).

Comment: This is a graph walking problem that requires recursion or looping.  BigQuery doesn't support this in a simple `SELECT`.  It does have looping mechanisms in the scripting language.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've been able to make it in vba. I divided it into two parts:

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've been able to make it in vba. I divided it into three parts: 1)Check if the first raw is not already in data (check both columns seaparately) 2)Look for the first column data (let's call it A) in whole table and write all the matchings. 3)Check all the matchings the same way as in point 2. And in general it works. It takes some time (~20 minutes) for code to execute. However with scripting I don't know how to get to this point. Finally I would like to have it scheduled so everyday proper match is there for me. Is there a way to connect python with bigquery schedule?

Comment: . . You can actually write the loop in the BQ scripting language (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting).  I'm pretty sure you can schedule scripts just as you would any other query:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries.

Comment: Ok, thx! For now vba is enough, scripting in bigquery is much more complicated than working on cells in excel via vba